# How to create a disk image from an APFS volume?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, disk-utility, apfs

I have an APFS encrypted 1TB SSD that I pulled from my now-dead MacBook Pro.  I placed the drive into a USB dock and can mount it fine after entering the disk password.  I cannot, however, take an image of this drive from Disk Utility.

When I select the volume, the New Image -> from "macOS" on the menu bar is grayed out.  As I understand it, this is normal for APFS volumes; you can only create images of APFS containers or physical disks.  When I select either the container or the disk, I can select New Image -> From [container or disk], but when I give it a file name and hit Save, all it does is tell me "Operation canceled."

I tried unmounting the volume first but got the same results.  I also tried to hit New Image -> From folder and selected /Volumes/macOS.  Then it gave me the error "Operation not permitted."

Thinking this was an issue with Catalina, I booted into Mojave and tried the same thing.  This time, Disk Utility created the image as expected, but when I try to open the it, I get an error "Disk image couldn't be opened.  Reason: No mountable file systems."

How can I take an image of this drive? Bearing in mind, I do not want to use 3rd-party software.  This is something that can be handled natively for non-APFS disks, and I don't see why it shouldn't work for APFS containers.

Oh, and one more thing:
First aid reports no errors with the volume.  I can read and write files to it just fine.  I just want an archival snapshot so I can re-purpose this SSD.  Thanks.

Comment: Is [ASR](https://github.com/toolbits/imagingAPFS) or dd an option?